# Aligning alternating lines of the text

Tags: alignment, text

I am trying to get used to using latex in all of my classes, but I am straggling a bit with some formatting issues.

I am trying to align alternating lines of the poem; I was wondering if there is a shortcut I could take using something like \align option for text entry?

This is approximately what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verse` package provides the environment of the same name, and a subenvironment `altverse` which shifts the even verses (alt=alternating). The indentation is governed by the `\vgap` length register.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
\itshape
\begin{altverse}
Across a world where all men grieve \\
And grieving strive the more, \\
The great days range like tides and leave \\
Our dead on every shore. \\
Heavy the load we undergo, \\
And our own hands prepare, \\
If we have parley with the foe, \\
The load our sons must bear.\par
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}

\setlength{\vgap}{3em}% just as example
\begin{verse}
\itshape
\begin{altverse}
Across a world where all men grieve \\
And grieving strive the more, \\
The great days range like tides and leave \\
Our dead on every shore. \\
Heavy the load we undergo, \\
And our own hands prepare, \\
If we have parley with the foe, \\
The load our sons must bear.\par
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @campa! One more question: for some reason neither \centering nor \begin{center} ... commands don't work with verse. Is there any way to introduce centring with it?

Comment: @ElenKhachatryan You can use `\settowidth{\versewidth}{Longest or average verse line}` (in this case `\settowidth{\versewidth}{The great days range like tides and leave}`) and then `\begin{verse}[\versewidth]`.